# can't get select option by value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select input. and I want to select an option by its value. 
when I run this code:

```
$('#monthYear').click(function(){
  op = $('#monthYear option[value="x"]');
  $(op).css('color','red');
});
```

nothing happens, so I ran:

```
console.log(op.value);
```

and it returned: `undefined`. can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Check out this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/63L8rtgh/3/). Thank you

html

```
<select id = "monthYear">
  <option>x</option>
  <option>y</option>
  <option>z</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can not override color property of select and its options. It is controlled by browsers.

Comment: Based on your HTML you should be using `op.text()`. Alternatively, if you want a value, you need to specify the value in the option: `<option value="x">x</option>` and using jQuery's `.val()` function to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. [Here's the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cas0tpun/).

```js
$('#monthYear').click(function(){
    op = $('#monthYear option[value="x"]');
    $(op).css('color','red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="monthYear">
    <option value="x">x</option>
    <option value="y">y</option>
    <option value="z">z</option>
</select>
```

I am unsure if this is what you want. All I did was add `value` attributes to your `<option>`s. Your jQuery selector wasn't working before.

Comment: that's all it need. i should have been selecting the option value, not the select value, thanks

Comment: You're very welcome. If my answer works for you, please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the check mark :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the value using jQuery, you must use `.val()`.

Or you can use `op[0].value`, that way you will get the first element that matches the variable `op` from jQuery object.

The snippet below shows that just the `x` valuated option will work

```js
$('#monthYear').click(function(){
  op = $('#monthYear option[value="x"]');
  op.css('color','red');
  console.log(op.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="monthYear">
  <option value="TEST">Choose Me</option>
  <option value="x">the X</option>
</select>
```

Comment: that works when I add value='x'. i was confused about the value of the option and the value of the select (assuming they were the same). now I see where i went wrong. thank you

Answer (score 1):

**You probably want to capture the event `change`:**

- Use this selector to get the selected option: `$('#monthYear option:selected')`
- The returned object is wrapped by jQuery, so to get the TEXT use the function `$.text()`.

```js
$('#monthYear').on('change', function() {
  var $op = $('#monthYear option:selected');
  $op.css('color', 'red');

  console.log($op.text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="monthYear">
  <option value="x">x</option>
  <option value="y">y</option>
  <option value="z">z</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `option` tags have no value at all so they cannot be selected by their value attribute, like `[value="x"]`. In your case `x` is just the text node of your `option` element. Try adding the attribute `value="x"` to your option tag and you'll reach the DOM element you want. And so your CSS will be applied to it.
https://jsfiddle.net/2ryq0w62/